# Combine a set of Uint8List

Tags: dart

I'm building a bunch of `Uint8List` (of different sizes, for now they are stored in a generic List) and I need to combine/concatenate them before sending on a websocket.

What would be the best approach ?

I though of combining them in a new Uint8List, but since I don't need byte access anymore after it is combined, I can maybe use a different `List<int>` implementation ... ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Uint8List` implements `List<int>`. You can combine them to a new `List<int>` and then create a new `Uint8List` with

```
List<List<int>> myByteLists = ...;
var bytes = Uint8List.fromList(myByteList.expand((x) => x).toList());
```

Answer (score 18):

Using [BytesBuilder](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-typed_data/BytesBuilder-class.html) seems to be the most efficient way to concatenate Uint8List's in Dart:

```
  var b = BytesBuilder();
  var l1 = Uint8List(4);
  var l2 = Uint8List(4);
  b.add(l1);
  b.add(l2);
  var ll = b.toBytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine them to a new Uint8List with:

```
List<Uint8List> list = [
    Uint8List.fromList([1, 2]),
    Uint8List.fromList([3, 4]),
    Uint8List.fromList([5, 6])
];
    
Uint8List bytes = list.reduce((x, y) => Uint8List.fromList(x + y));
```